# Posso usar o Repository para fazer a parte de BLL?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern

Estava lendo sobre Repository vs Dao e vi a seguinte frase:

> [...] Já o padrão Repository tem o objetivo de dar apoio ao domain model
>   fornecendo persistência. Ao contrário do DAO, que é um objeto de
>   infra-estrutura da aplicação e faz parte da camada de persistência, o
>   Repository faz parte do domain model que é parte da camada de
>   negócios.

Então, o repository pode ser usado como classe para BLL ?

Answer (score 4):

**Depende:** Se no seu projeto você deseja que sua camada de negócio (BLL) não tenha referências a tecnologias de acesso a dados, mapeamento de dados, etc... da estrutura do seu projeto você pode usar esse *design pattern*. Mas a implementação do *Repository* não vai ficar necessariamente dentro da sua camada de negócio (BLL).

***Repository*** isola os objetos de domínio (relacionados ao negócio) de detalhes do código de acesso e mapeamento desses objetos com o banco de dados. Ou seja, ele adiciona uma camada de **separação** entre as camadas de acesso a dados e de domínio.

Isso significa que se você tem uma camada de negócios (BLL) na sua aplicação, você pode utilizar esse *design pattern* para ter uma separação clara entre sua camadas de acesso a dados e sua camada de negócio.

`Por que ter essa separação e cenário onde utilizei:`

Eu trabalhei um pouco com *Domain Driven Design* (**[DDD](http://ehbomcompartilhar.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/domain-driven-design-ddd.html)**) e nesse cenário se você coloca o seu *Repository* dentro da sua camada de negócio, você pode acabar tendo referências de tecnologias (exemplo NHibernate, Entity, etc..), o que não é recomendado (uma vez que regras de negócio não tem relação com as tecnologias utilizadas no projeto, a idéia aqui é você não misturar essas duas coisas) quando se utiliza DDD.

Nesse caso então nós inserimos a(s) **Interface**(s) do(s) repositório(s) na camada de negócio, deixando com que a camada de infra-estrutura implemente as interfaces de repositório e, esta camada sim, tenha referência as tecnologias utilizadas para recuperação, persistência de dados, etc.

Answer (score 2):

O **`Repository`** não só pode ficar na **`BLL`**(*`Business Logic Layer`*), como é o lugar dele, ele servirá basicamente como o intermediário da sua aplicação para a sua **`DAL`** (*`Data Access Layer`*) onde fica  seu **`DAO`**.

Claro que dependendo da arquitetura, do tamanho do projeto, ou do **"eu quero assim e ponto final"**, você pode também aninhar os dois sob a mesma camada.

Comment: Então serial ClassBLL -> ClassRepository -> ClassDAL. 
O repository seria um intermediário da DAL, Dal teria acesso de dados(insert,delete, update,select) que passaria para o Repository que poderia ter outros gets (getClienteBy algumacoisa) e a BLL iria fazer a validação em si e a regra do negócio "ao add pedido, vincular produtos com cliente, blabala" Isso?

Answer (score 1):

Já implementei regras de negócio (BLL) dentro de classes de Repositório (DAO).
Não ví problemas nisso, e é bem prático.

Quando houver necessidade, você pode refatorar o código facilmente, e extrair este código para uma classe BLL.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode abstrair a Repository em uma camada a mais na sua aplicação, e não é errado aplicar suas regras de negocio dentro dela. Seria errado se você estivesse fazendo isso diretamente na DAO